# Compass accuracy dilemma

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, digital-compass

I need to build compass for my application.

From reading the documentation it seems there are two reasonable ways of doing this:

- Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION method: This is the easy way of doing it. The problem with this is it is not accurate. When I compare my reading with Snaptic Compass it is about 10-15 degress off which for my purposes is unacceptable.
- Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD and getRotationMatrix() in conjunction with remapCoordinateSystem() and getOrientation() method: The documentation says this "is usually more accurate". The problem is regardless of the delay I register with listener the compass goes crazy even when the device is stationary on flat surface.

Any suggestions for solving this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like mob1lejunkie has figured this out already, but just for future reference, let me mention that the issue here is [magnetic declination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination) (the difference between magnetic north and true north). You can try out [an online model from NOAA](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomagmodels/Declination.jsp) to get a sense for what the difference is in your part of the world.

Android includes a model called [GeomagneticField](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.html) that can be used to compute the approximate declination given a latitude, longitude, and altitude. So, what I believe you need to do to compute true north is read out the [azimuth value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) from Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION and then add to that GeomagneticField.getDeclination().

Comment: Yes this was exactly the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's the downside of compact parts made for phones.  A $5000 IMU that we're using right now has an error of +/- 2 degrees and in that range it seems to go crazy as well.

Try stepping away from interference, metal surfaces, and see if it improves.  If not, I hate to break the bad news, but that's the hardware.

Have you seen these?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bbb0e8b97c673cf9/5c16bc2e49f6e972?lnk=raot

Comment: What I am trying to say is on the same phone (Nexus One) at the exact identical place on the kitchen table Snaptic Compass, a third party application from Android Market, is more accurate then my reading. 

I am wondering what trick Snaptic is using to get more accurate and reliable reading.

Comment: After poking around in Snaptic Compass settings I noticed it uses true north whereas I was using magnetic north. Now that I also use true north my application and Snaptic Compass have same reading. Of course reading isn't perfect but that is due to Nexus One hardware not a fault of my compass implementation.

pinnacler thanks for your help!